# URL structure changed. need to 301 redirect some old .html urls that returns 404 to the root

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect

I have a problem with my website, after redesign and site structure has dramaticly changed.
The old pages were like this www.site.com/page.html but the new one is managed with wordpress and urls are now without .html in the end.

Not all the old pages have been recreated in the new site but 15-20 of them were, so i added in htaccess 301 redirects from the old urls to the new ones.

The problem i have now is that a lot of old .html pages don't exist anymore and i am missing some links, juice and traffic because of that and i would like to redirect all the remaingin .html pages to the root domain of the new one. Don't know what rules to apply because 20 old .html pages are allready redirected and i don't want those pages to redirect to the root, just the ones that don't exist anymore and are returning 404's.

Any piece of advice on this? I am not so fammiliar with apache even if i tried to find an answer online, haven't figured it out yet. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to provide your current code. See [the help center guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Guy This should work for redirecting the old urls to the new ones whitout .html but this will not redirect the 20 pages i allready redirected to the new ones? I want to redirect all .html urls to the root but exclude just some specific urls and i think your solution will redirect all of them to the root.   If i use your line of code what will happen with the pages that are redirecting allready to the new ones? Thanks for taking time to help me.

Comment: I think you meant to comment on Guy's answer.

Comment: you're right, this is my first day here so i can make some silly mistakes. thanks for your note!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule (*.html) http://www.your.site [R=301,L]
```

If you have other rules, you can add this afterwards as long as you have the `L` flag. This will stop processing rules once one is matched. E.g.

```
RewriteRule page.html http://www.your.site/page [R=301,L]
RewriteRule (*.html) http://www.your.site [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This should work for redirecting the old urls to the new ones whitout .html but this will not redirect the 20 pages i allready redirected to the new ones? I want to redirect all .html urls to the root but exclude just some specific urls and i think your solution will redirect all of them to the root. If i use your line of code what will happen with the pages that are redirecting allready to the new ones? Thanks for taking time to help me. –

Comment: If you add this rule after your other rules, and make sure to contain the `L` flag, this will stop processing any further rules once it is matched.